# Push Notification received, but no message

Tags: java, android, vb.net, push-notification

I am developing an android app, which needs to receive the push notification.

The push notification is received but there is no message, just when I click on launcher icon in notification it launched app, but no message is received.

I am here handling only the receiving notification part, the notification is sent by some other guy from server and he is using VB.net for that, cant check his code. But I can post mine.
My onMessage:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {


  Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
  String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");


  generateNotification(context, message);
```

}

My generateNotification

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
          context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
  String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CoursesMainActivity.class);
  // set intent so it does not start a new activity
  notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  PendingIntent intent =
          PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  // Play default notification sound

  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
 // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
  notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
  }
```

Please help with this, if someone wants to VB.net code for sending message I can provide that too.

Thanks,
Asmi

Comment: have you debugged your code ???? `String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price")`; What you are getting at this line ??

Comment: Thanks for the message was null, resolved it now

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it as the other person(sending the push notification) was not sending it as "price", but as "message"